# Converting ASCII code to char in Java

Tags: java

Here's my code below and it prints J=74, A =65, and M=77. How do I get it to print just the characters K, B, N as the result of moving down the alphabet?

```
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( " Please Enter Code " );

for (int i = 0; i < string.length (); ++i) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    int j = (int)c;
}


System.out.println("ASCII OF "+c +" = " + j + ".");
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply casting `int` to `char`

```
System.out.println((char) 65);        // A
System.out.println((char) ('A' + 1)); // B
System.out.println((int) 'A');        // 65
```

Beware, this is a raw attempt at a *naive* problem (or at least a bad spoken one). The last line of your snippet already contains everything you need. Maybe you only miss that `char` in Java is really an integer type, so you can use `char` literals with operators like `+` or even `%`

```
System.out.println((char) ('Z' + 5));
System.out.println((char) ('Z' / 2));
System.out.println((char) ('Z' % 31));
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you have already given ur answer in question itself.
You should cast the integer to char as below

```
    int j=77;
    char c=(char)j;
    System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean?

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length (); ++i) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    c++; // next character.
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: A 21st century "real programmer" can write `C++` in any language.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

ASCII characters can have zero at the begining, because of that conversion from String to Integer have to be done correctly. Working solution is shown below.

```
    String s= "01001000";
    int AsciiCode = Integer.valueOf(s, 2);
    char c= (char) AsciiCode;
    System.out.println(c);
```