# How to replace ascii characters by unicode characters?

Tags: java, unicode

I get one String from properties file in which uni-code is stored as `-uni-000A` which is actually `\u000A`. When I write this `\u000A` in another file I want to write its corresponding unicode character i.e. `\n` but my program is writting `\u000A` instead of `\n`.

Can anyone please tell how to replace `-uni-000A` to `\u000A` and tell program to get its corresponding character?

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012871/converting-ascii-code-to-char-in-java

Comment: Is the issue arising with only `\u000A` LF unicode or all the others as well? If you try and print some other unicode like `\u0940` does it work fine?

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to forget the encoding of your source file - once you have read a String, every character in java is treated the same.

Now your problem is to write the characters in your String to bytes in a specific encoding.  For that you can use one of the different Writer implementations.  Say you need to write your characters in Unicode:

```
    String myString = ...; /* Wherever it comes from */
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
new FileOutputStream("/home/shekhar/myFile"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    writer.write(myString);
    writer.close();
```

This should make sure the corresponding bytes for an 8 bit Unicode are written into your file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using methods of `StringEscapeUtils` class in `commons-lang`.

Its a two step process :

1. First escape `\u` character by using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\\u")`
2. Whenever you want to need actual unicode representation then use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()` method.

Giving my sample code here :

```
String unic = "__UNICODE__000A";
String replaced = unic.replaceAll("__UNICODE__", StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\\u"));

// below line prints \u000A
System.out.println("replaced = " + replaced);
String finalVal = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(replaced);

// below line prints actual \n character
System.out.println("final = " + finalVal);
```

Hope it helps. Thanks everyone for your valuable answers and comments.