# How do I read nothing else but a String using exceptions?

Tags: java, string, exception, letter

would you be so kind and help me please? Im doing a simple quiz game, during the game the user is asked to enter his answer. Its either A,B or C. i would like to have this covered with try/catch exceptions...

What I want this code to do, is to throw exception (force the user the enter the answer again) whenever he will enter something else than a String.
here is the part of a code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = "";
boolean invalidInput = true;

while(invalidInput){
    try {
        answer = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        invalidInput = false;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
         System.out.println("Enter a letter please");
         invalidInput = true;
    }
}
```

The problem now is, that if I enter an integer, it won't throw anything.

Thanks

Comment: how about reading chars instead of integers, and filtering the char codes? something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945695/how-to-filter-string-for-unwanted-characters-using-regex  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012871/converting-ascii-code-to-char-in-java

Comment: @Nagarz your comment should be an answer ;-)

Comment: @LionC maybe, but it's more of an idea than an answer, because it's not what he asked for exactly.

Comment: get the use of regex in your case

Comment: I would use if statements right away, but the task was given by the teacher, to handle entered values by exceptions... Im supposed to do it this way otherwise the teacher won't accept it. but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply throw an `InputMismatchException` if the data are not as you expected.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = "";
boolean invalidInput = true;    
while(invalidInput){
    try {
        answer = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        if (!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") && !answer.equals("C")) {
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        } 
        invalidInput = false;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a letter please");
        invalidInput = true;
    }
}
```

Note that is not necessary to throw an Exception for this kind of controls. You can handle the error message directly in the if code.

Comment: Throwing the InputMismatchException if needed

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for. I wanted to use if statements from the beginning, but the task was to use exceptions... this the combination of it, and it works smoothly like a baby's butt. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem now is, that if I enter an integer, it won't throw
>   anything.

No the problem is you thinking it's an integer , it's actually String .

```
String s=1; //Gives Compilation Error
```

while

```
 String s="1"; // will not give any Error/Exception and this is your case
```

User will provide  inputs until it met your Expected Input List , something like this :

```
List<String> expectedInputs=Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D");
String input=takeInputFromUser();
if(expectedInputs.contains(input)){
     //doWhatever you want to do 
}else{
     // throw any Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `regex` in this case

```
try {
    answer = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    invalidInput = !answer.matches("[ABC]");                
} catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Enter a letter please");
    invalidInput = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, noticed. Though, I was forced by the teacher to use exceptions. Next time I will do it this way.