# How do I convert a single character code to a `char` given a character set?

Tags: java, ascii

I want to convert decimal to ascii and this is the code returns the unexpected results. Here is the code I am using.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char ret= (char)146;  
    System.out.println(ret);// returns nothing.
```

I expect to get character single "'" as per http://www.ascii-code.com/
Anyone came across this? Thanks.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is a misnomer. ASCII is by definition up to 127 only. There are character sets which extend that range, but how they do that varies wildly. So you really need to know what you're talking about. What your doing in your code, is printing the Unicode codepoint 146 which coincides with the single upper quote, luckily: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm

Comment: Maybe your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012871/converting-ascii-code-to-char-in-java

Comment: in my input I have decimals greater than 127. Some gets converted correctly but some like '146' gives trouble.

Comment: Your characters are not ASCII.  They are most likely [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  In the windows-1252 charset, 146 is actually `'\u2019'`.  If you want to see the correct character, change your code to `(char)0x2019` or `'\u2019'`.

Comment: Your terminal might not be using the same encoding as the one whose numeric code you are assuming will output the character you want. So, the program and terminal are both doing exactly the right thing, it's just that they don't interpret the numeric value the way you expect, because they are using a different encoding.

Comment: Looks like I need to find the encoding setting from where I am receiving the data.
also looking to see if I can convert '146' to windows-1252 and then convert to char
Really useful replies here. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to improve the general applicability of this question with a title edit. It's possible that I just made a mess or made it confusing. Feel free to rollback or whatever.

Comment: The following link ... http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html ... contains a program that can show you what encoding you are using. There are methods to set the encoding, but I seem to recall that the encoding is set at the time the JVM starts, and that changing it is problematic. The thing to do is either force output in a specific encoding, or to find the default encoding and get the number of the codepoint you want in that encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, a couple of things.

First of all the page you linked to says this about the code point range in question:

> **The extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255)**
>
> There are several different variations of the 8-bit ASCII table. The table below is according to ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1. Codes 128-159 contain the Microsoft® Windows Latin-1 extended characters.

This is incorrect, or at least, to me, misleadingly worded. **[ISO 8859-1 / Latin-1 does not define code point 146](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) (and [another reference just because](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495(v=vs.85).aspx))**. So that's already asking for trouble. You can see this also if you do the conversion through `String`:

```
String s = new String(new byte[] {(byte)146}, "iso-8859-1");
System.out.println(s);
```

Outputs the same "unexpected" result. It *appears* that what they are actually referring to is the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) set (aka "Windows Latin-1", but this name is almost completely obsolete these days), which does define that code point as a right single quote (for other charsets that provide this character at 146 see [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/charset_support.htm) and look for encodings that provide it at 0x92), and we can verify this as such:

```
String s = new String(new byte[] {(byte)146}, "windows-1252");
System.out.println(s);
```

So the first mistake is that page is confusing.

But the big mistake is you can't do what you're trying to do in the way you are doing it. A `char` in Java is a UTF-16 code point (or half of one, if you're representing the supplementary characters > 0xFFFF, a single `char` corresponds to a BMP point, a pair of them or an `int` corresponds to the full range, including the supplementary ones).

Unfortunately, Java doesn't really expose a lot of API for single-character conversions. Even [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) doesn't have any readily available ways to convert from the charset of your choice to UTF-16.

So one option is to do it via `String` as hinted at in the examples above, e.g. express your code points as a raw `byte[]` array and convert from there:

```
String s = new String(new byte[] {(byte)146}, "windows-1252");
System.out.println(s);
char c = s.charAt(0);
System.out.println(c);
```

You could grab the `char` again via `s.charAt(0)`. Note that you have to be mindful of your character set when doing this. Here we know that our byte sequence is valid for the specified encoding, and we know that the result is only one `char` long, so we can do this.

However, you have to watch out for things in the general case. For example, perhaps your byte sequence and character set yield a result that is in the UTF-16 supplementary character range. In that case `s.charAt(0)` would not be sufficient and `s.codePointAt(0)` stored in an `int` would be required instead.

As an alternative, with the same caveats, you could use [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to decode, although it's just as clunky, e.g.:

```
Charset cs = Charset.forName("windows-1252");
CharBuffer cb = cs.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {(byte)146}));
char c = cb.get(0);
System.out.println(c);
```

Note that I am not entirely sure how `Charset#decode` handles supplementary characters and can't really test right now (but anybody, feel free to chime in).

---

As an aside: In your case, 146 (0x92) cast directly to `char` corresponds to the UTF-16 character "PRIVATE USE TWO" ([see also](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF#ref_PU2)), and all bets are off for what you'll end up displaying there. This character is [classified by Unicode as a control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#Private-use_characters_in_other_character_sets), and seems to fall in the range of characters reserved for ANSI terminal control (although AFAIK isn't actually used, but it's in that range regardless). I wouldn't be surprised if perhaps browsers in some locales rendered it as a right-single-quote for compatibility, but terminals did something weird with it.

Also, fyi, the official UTF-16 code point for [right single quote is 0x2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm). You could reliably store that in a `char` by using that value, e.g.:

```
System.out.println((char)0x2019);
```

You can also see this for yourself by looking at the value after the conversion from windows-1252:

```
String s = new String(new byte[] {(byte)146}, "windows-1252");
char c = s.charAt(0);
System.out.printf("0x%x\n", (int)c); // outputs 0x2019
```

Or, for completeness:

```
String s = new String(new byte[] {(byte)146}, "windows-1252");
int cp = s.codePointAt(0);
System.out.printf("0x%x\n", cp); // outputs 0x2019
```

Comment: Reading this informative post raised the question in my mind why the language allows the (char) type cast at all, or, if it does, why it doesn't require, or at least allow, the encoding be specified along with it, for example (char:cp1252) integer_variable or whatever.  There are dozens of single-byte encoding schemes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Comment: @Thomas Well, it allows the cast because there's no reason not to, and it'd have to be a weird special case, as casts between compatible types are allowed in all other cases. It'd be unnecessarily limiting and at the cost of implementing special case compiler error.

Comment: As for the 2nd question, the encoding is implied: char is UTF-16. Period. Sure it would be *convenient* if you could specify an encoding and have the compiler wrap that in a Charset lookup for you, but it'd just be sugar. And also that means some casts would require handling of the exceptions Charset.forName can throw (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName(java.lang.String)). Also I have a feeling single char encoding is a relatively rare use case, hence the weak API here. I'd rather see a Character constructor that takes a Charset name.

Comment: (Also note that in your proposed scheme of specifying charset name in the cast, I wonder what a use case for it would be. First, it means you know, at compile time, the encoding. Which granted is the same as you hard-coding a character set name when reading strings but I feel that in the latter case, you at least leave the flexibility of user choosable encodings in the future, which philosophically seems like a better implementation to me, rather than completely shutting down the possibility. Second, 99.9% of the time, you're operating on Strings instead, which we've got good API for.)

Comment: You say " there's no reason not to [allow the cast]" and ask "I wonder what a use case for it would be [for specifying charset name in the cast]". I would turn the question around: what possible use is a (char) type cast if it is output in an encoding that almost no one uses (Windows uses CP1252 and Linux uses UTF-8), or if you DON'T know the encoding in which it will be output? Many people reading this didn't know that JVM uses UTF-16 internally. And if 99.9% of the time you're operating on Strings instead of chars, then that also begs the question of what the (char) type cast is for?

Answer (score 0):

The page you refer mention that values 160 to 255 correspond to the ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin 1) table; as for values in the range 128 to 159, they are from the Windows specific variant of the Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1 leave that range undefined, to be assigned by operating system).

Java characters are based on UTF16, which is itself based on the Unicode table. If you want to specifically refer to the right quote character, it is you can specify it as `'\u2019'` in Java (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).